# Does loading a php file count as a HTTP request?

Tags: php, http, codeigniter

For example in codeigniter you can use:

```
<?php $this->load->view('some_php_file'); ?>
```

If I had multiple of those loads, would each one count as a http request as it is loading a external file?

Answer (score 3):

An HTTP request is when you use the HTTP Protocol to request a document. That code looks like is just includes another PHP file from the same server into the PHP script being processed so that would not be an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter being a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) web application framework, when you use

`$this->load->view('name');`

you are telling to the framework to open the file containing the View (V of MVC) from your server's hard drive and to include it in the final client response.

So there is no HTTP request when [loading views in CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).